# Are comments flagged as unkind also auto-deleted?

Tags: support, flags, comments, unfriendly-or-unkind

I'm aware that sometimes comments that are marked as not needed, can get auto-deleted, if they contain obvious markers such as `thanks`, or `very helpful`.

Today, I reported a comment as unkind. And it got auto-deleted immediately.

The comment was along the lines

> What have you tried so far? Did you hear the term `XYZ-Framework`?

So is there an auto delete for such comments as well?

Does it delete/hide all the comments marked as unkind? Or is there some code that tries to detect?

Comment: Yes ⁮ ⁮ ⁮ ⁮ ⁮ ⁮ ⁮

Comment: Is it the "What have you tried?" That's letting this be auto deleted when flagged?

Comment: I wouldn't flag that example as unkind, though. Maybe that's why I'm occasionally called an vqvbg. :(

Comment: @E_net4 To me, first part is absolutely important. But the second part could have been phrased better.

Comment: And... this is the problem with the new CoC. There is absolutely nothing "unkind" about that comment - it does 2 things: Asks for clarification as to what the asker has done on their own before asking, and ***provides a resource for them***. Flagging and auto-deleting that *deprives the OP of potentially useful information*. Remember, not everyone on SO is a native speaker, so give the benefit of the doubt when you see things like "Did you hear the term XYZ-Framework". That's no more "abusive" than "Have you tried XYZ-Framework"?

Answer (score 2):

Comments are automatically deleted if they accumulate enough flags, and if you cast the last required flag, it looks to you like it's one-flag-deleted. Voted comments require more flags before they're auto-deleted.

Comments containing certain keywords (like a word starting with F) will be deleted upon receiving its first flag, but AFAICT the comment you presented would not.

Answer (score -12):

## Comments like this are useless waste of time for everyone involved.

Waste of time for the commentor, waste of time for those reading the comment and a waste of time of everyone on meta reading about the waste of time on arguing about comments like this being *unkind or not*.

How about this, **Down Vote and Move On**. *What have you tried?* adds nothing that the **hover text of the down vote arrow does not already say!**

> "This question **does not show any research effort**; it is unclear or
> not useful"

*Emphasis mine*

If you are recommending them to use some framework then the question is **Off-Topic: Recommendations** and just **Flag/Vote to Close and Move On**.

Comments are not productive and more likely to produce toxic behavior *(real or imagined)* than positive behavior on the part of everyone involved so why spend the time to do it?

Comment: It's not "just" a WHYT. The comment is just another way to make the OP do some more research on XYZ-framework.